# Sitemap after changing domain?

Tags: seo, xml-sitemap

my client migrated to a new domain. I redirected all old URLs to the new ones.
My concern is about the old sitemap. What should I do with the old sitemap? Should I delete it from my search console?

Comment: If you **redirected all old URLs** that enough.

Answer (score 1):

If you leave it in search console, this should help Googlebot find the new pages because the URLs in the old sitemap should now redirect to pages on the new domain.

In any case, if you have global redirects in place (meaning any request to the old domain is redirected to the new domain), and your new sitemap is referenced in your robots.txt file, then Googlebot will find it.

More information:
https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/crawling/site-move-with-url-changes